`typing.get_origin` vs. `TypeAlias.__origin__`
Python's docs define GenericAlias.__origin__ as:

This attribute points at the non-parameterized generic class
list[int].__origin__  # returns list

There is also typing.get_origin, which is defined differently:

Get the unsubscripted version of a type: for a typing object of the form X[Y, Z, ...] return X.

So usually, there is no practical difference - get_origin(cls) is usually equivalent to getattr(cls, '__origin__', None). But I've run into at least one case where they're different:
>>> get_origin(Annotated[int, 3])
typing.Annotated
>>> Annotated[int, 3].__origin__
int

So, my questions are:

Why are there 2 conflicting definitions of "origin"?
If I don't care about the metadata encoded in a typing.Annotation, and just want to know the type hint, is there a "right way" to strip out the Annotation wrapper? E.g., do I need  to unwrap every single type object with if get_origin(cls) is typing.Annotated: cls = cls.__origin__ to make sure that get_origin will behave as expected?


Could you be more specific about "If I don't care about annotations"? Are you saying you don't care about Annotated metadata, or you don't care about annotations at all? Because code that doesn't care about annotations should never have to deal with this in the first place.

Conflicting definitions
I initially considered this a documentation omission, but it isn't.
First, typing.Annotated[X, ...] is not a types.GenericAlias:
from typing import Annotated
assert not issubclass(type(Annotated[int, ""]), type(list[int]))

So the documentation of GenericAlias.__origin__ does not and should not apply here.
typing.get_origin behaves as per specification: returns the unparametrized version, Annotated itself.
Annotated[...].__origin__ is documented under typing.Annotated:

At runtime, if you want to retrieve the original type wrapped by Annotated, use the __origin__ attribute
[snip]
Note that using get_origin() will return Annotated itself

Runtime inspection

If I don't care about annotations in my runtime type handling code, is there a "right way" to strip them out?

Yes. If you want to handle Annotated[T, ...] as if it was just T, you can
if typing.get_origin(tp) is typing.Annotated:
    tp = tp.__origin__

as you suggest, and that sounds like the most reasonable approach to me.
However, if you use runtime introspection, that often means that types are coming from typing.get_type_hints, and it does all the heavy lifting for you:

By default, get_type_hints() strips the metadata from annotations. Pass include_extras=True to have the metadata preserved


"[...] typing.Annotated[X, ...] is not a typing.GenericAlias:" I think you meant to say types.GenericAlias. There is no typing.GenericAlias, only the private typing._GenericAlias which Annotated[T, ...] is an instance of: type(Annotated[int, ...]).__mro__  # (_AnnotatedAlias, _NotIterable, _GenericAlias, _BaseGenericAlias, _Final, object).

Yeah @InSync, that should be types.GenericAlias, thanks for spotting!
